# Microsoft Graph API transient user filter

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way for me to get back ONLY users when I call List group transitive users in graph API?

The response I get has objects for groups as well as users EG:

```
{group: IT support},

{user: Kevin},
{user: Bob},
{user: Phil},

{group: Developers},

{user:phil}
```

Id like to be able to filter out the group objects but no dice. Has anyone been able to do this before? Thanks

Comment: Which api did you call? Could you provide a sample of the response you want?

Comment: Lack of information. No api call, no response example...

Comment: I have got an response from the Azure support engineer, '@odata.type' is not supported to be a query param here.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, we can use [$filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#filter-parameter) query parameter to retrieve the response we need, but it seems that '@odata.type' is not supported to be a query param here. I will double confirm with Azure support engineer.

By the way, the response is in json format, you can write a filter yourself to get the user objects only.

**Update:**

I have got an response from the Azure support engineer, '@odata.type' is not supported to be a query param here. So you need to deal with the data by yourself.